# How to solve "Access violating reading location error" in c++?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Goodday all, 
I'm getting the following error:

`First-chance exception at 0x67887AB7 (SDL2_mixer.dll) in Racing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD4.`

I think the problem could be with the pointer, but I'm not experienced enough in c++ to find it. 
I'm hoping someone can tell me what I did wrong, and hopefully I can learn from it :)

Trying to call it from my gamebus.

```
Music Mus;
Mus.SpeelGeluid("crash");
```

Music class

```
bool Music::LoadMusic(){
    //Load music
    Mix_Music *gMusic = NULL;
    gMusic = Mix_LoadMUS("MusicTest.wav");
    Mix_PlayMusic(gMusic, -1);
    bool success = true;
    if (gMusic == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to load Music background song! SDL_mixer Error: %s\n", Mix_GetError());
        success = false;
    }

    // Load sound effects
    Mix_Chunk *gCrash = NULL;
    gCrash = Mix_LoadWAV("Crash.wav");
    if (gCrash == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to load scratch sound effect! SDL_mixer Error: %s\n", Mix_GetError());
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

void Music::SpeelGeluid(string soundname){
cout << soundname << endl;

if (soundname == "crash")
{
    try
    {
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1, gCrash, 0);
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << '\n';
    }
} 
else
{
}   }
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Yes, it's probably a pointer. However, we're not going to be able to debug your code. You need to step through it in a a debugger or put print statements in to narrow the problem down.

Comment: You need to check `gMusic` for `NULL` before `Mix_PlayMusic(gMusic, -1);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major problems:

First, you're using `gMusic` before checking whether it's `NULL`.
This may crash `Mix_PlayMusic`, and actually means that compilers may optimise out the later `NULL` check.

Second, and most likely the cause of your problem, you're declaring `gCrash` and `gMusic` as local variables in `LoadMusic`.
From the names, and your use of `gCrash` in `SpeelGeluid`, my educated guess is that you also have two global variables, or possibly member variables, with the same names where you *intend* to store the results of loading the files.

Your local variables are hiding these globals, and you're only modifying the local variables.

Remove the lines

```
Mix_Music *gMusic = NULL;
```

and

```
Mix_Chunk *gCrash = NULL;
```

to get rid of these local variables.

And do initialise the globals to `NULL` when you define them.

Comment: Aren't globals auto initialised by the compiler so a pointer would get a null value assigned... or was that just C?

Answer (score 1):

Check your pointers as soon as you've allocated them and handle them appropriately. You nearly do:

```
gMusic = Mix_LoadMUS("MusicTest.wav");
Mix_PlayMusic(gMusic, -1); // <- You're using the pointer here before you check it
bool success = true;
if (gMusic == NULL) // <- this needs to be immediately after assignment
```

That's just from the code you've pointed. It's also possible you've missed a generic initialisation call from the SDL2_mixer.dll.

Do debug it and step through line by line so you know which bit is causing the error.